# How to vertical align the first item?

Tags: html, css

I've been trying : text-align:center,  align-items:center..
In this code, I use BootStrap, but I also tried to over-code it via css- nothing helps.
I'd really thank you for help.

```html
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>HTML Final Task</title>
        <!-- CSS only -->
        <link
          href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor"
          crossorigin="anonymous"
        />
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css"
        />
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="nav-container-wrap">
          <div class="nav container py-3 justify-content-between text-center">
            <div class="left-box d-flex gap-5">
              <div class="nav-item"><h3>Adantrip</h3></div>
              <div class="nav-item"><p>Hotels</p></div>
              <div class="nav-item"><p>Rooms</p></div>
              <div class="nav-item"><p>Flights</p></div>
              <div class="nav-item"><p>Cars</p></div>
              <div class="nav-item"><p>Experiences</p></div>
            </div>
            <div class="right-box d-flex gap-5">
              <div class="nav-item">USD</div>
              <div class="nav-item"><i class="fa-solid fa-flag-usa"></i></div>
              <div class="nav-item">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-user"></i> My Account
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of the HTML `<p>` and `<h1>` tags are throwing off the Bootstrap layout because of their default attributes. Rather than fight with them, use the classes that Bootstrap provides. `align-items-center` on your flex containers and the responsive `h1` class on the item you want for your header.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>HTML Final Task</title>
  <!-- CSS only -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="nav-container-wrap">
    <div class="nav container py-3 justify-content-between align-items-center text-center ">
      <div class="left-box d-flex align-items-center text-center gap-5">
        <div class="nav-item h1">Adantrip</div>
        <div class="nav-item">Hotels</div>
        <div class="nav-item">Rooms</div>
        <div class="nav-item">Flights</div>
        <div class="nav-item">Cars</div>
        <div class="nav-item">Experiences</div>
      </div>
      <div class="right-box d-flex gap-5">
        <div class="nav-item">USD</div>
        <div class="nav-item"><i class="fa-solid fa-flag-usa"></i></div>
        <div class="nav-item">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-user"></i> My Account
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code. Some Bootstrap default styles, same as margin-bottom in some tags, affect your code.

Let's make it simple and see the difference then correct it.
In this sample, I'm gonna use pure CSS.
Remove Bootstrap from your code temporarily and then add these styles:

```
.nav{display:flex;justify-content:space-between}
.left-box,
.right-box{display:flex;align-items:center;gap: 0.5rem;}
```

Comment: Hi, for some reason it still doesn't fit the center (the "Adantrip" header); I did see that it has affected the nav-container, but it hasn't solved the problem.